# How to verify laravel default flash messages in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, php

How can i verify any laravel default flash message in selenium? Whether it displayed or not after the execution ? I can't locate the flash message as it was showing after page load.
Providing my controller code for flash message  below...

[image]

```
\Session::flash('flash_message', 'Question paper ' .ucwords(strtolower($request->Title)). ' added successfully');
 \Session::flash('alert-class', 'success');
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question with PHP? Php builds your html page?

Comment: Not for any particular reason..As my project was built by php-laravel ..that's why i mentioned the tag php there

Comment: *I can't locate the flash message as it was showing after page load*. Why is this a problem? Can you add some your code trials? I do not see any potential problem to catch flash message.

Comment: i just added the inspect section above. The real problem which i am facing is, how can i verify the success flash message ? How can i locate this message in selenium?

Answer (score 1):

As per your screen shot there is a pre-defined text that fills your flash message. So what you could do is to set up `FluentWait` object that would use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(...)`.

Like:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                   (By.xpath("//*[text()='TEXT_OF_FLASH_MESSAGE']")));
```

Make sure you have configured **reasonably small polling interval** so that you will catch even fast flash messages.

Put that waiter right after the line that brings you to the page that loads that flash-message.

Details on how to use `FLuentWait`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336948/how-to-use-built-in-expectedconditions-with-fluentwait